Method of separation of variables; non-homogeneous linear equation

\begin{cases}
 \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{ \partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}+u \\
 u(x,0)=4e^{2x}-e^{-x}; x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}

I have tried solving the problem above assuming that $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$, but I couldn't express $Y$ as a function only depending on $y$.
Using the substition $ v=u_x$:
\begin{cases}
v = v_y +u \\
 u(x,0)=4e^{2x}-e^{-x}; x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}
$$v_y-v=-u \iff \frac{\partial(ve^{-y})}{\partial y}=-ue^{-y} \iff ve^{-y}=\int-ue^{-y}dy+f(x)$$
But now I can't seem to find a way to continue the resolution. Any suggestions?

Plugging in $u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$ separates cleanly into $1 - X/X' = Y'/Y$.

Then, is it possible to write $Y$ as a function of solely $y$?

First of all, assuming that $u(x,y)$ takes the form $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$ we find that
$$
X'Y=X'Y'+XY \qquad \implies \qquad 1-Y'/Y=X/X'=\lambda
$$
Solving the equation for $Y(y)$ we get that
$$
Y'+(\lambda-1)Y=0 \qquad \implies \qquad Y_\lambda(y)=Ce^{-(\lambda-1)y}.
$$
Similarly, solving the equation for $X(x)$, $$
X'-\frac{1}{\lambda}X=0 \qquad \implies \qquad X_\lambda(x)=Ce^{x/\lambda}.
$$
In particular, choosing $\lambda=1/2$ and $\lambda=-1$ we obtain
$$
u_{1/2}(x,y)=X_{1/2}(x)Y_{1/2}(y)=C_1e^{2x+y/2}
$$
$$
u_{-1}(x,y)=X_{-1}(x)Y_{-1}(y)=C_2e^{-x+2y}
$$
Then, defining $u(x,y)=u_{1/2}(x,y)+u_{-1}(x,y)$, using the boundary condition we infer that $$
u(x,0)=u_{1/2}(x,0)+u_{-1}(x,0)=C_1e^{2x}+C_2e^{-x}=4e^{2x}-e^{-x},
$$
implying that $C_1=4$ and $C_2=-1$. Therefore, the solution is $$
u(x,y)=4e^{2x+y/2}-e^{-x+2y}.
$$

why can we define $u(x,y)$ as $u_{\frac{1}{2}}(x,y) + u_{-1}(x,y)$ ?

For every $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ the function defined as $u_\lambda(x,y)=X_\lambda(x)Y_\lambda(y)$ solves the PDE. However, there are only two possible values of $\lambda$ that can lead to a function such that, on top of satisfying the PDE, satisfies the boundary condition.
